# Making download links from short code

Tags: links

I want to create a word press download page with links to all my downloadable files (various types) and keep a running total of downloads.  WPMP seems to do this but I cannot seem to create the link in plain text.

Comment: Carmel, what have you tried? what exactly is the problem?  Do you understand that for a download link to work, it needs to be an html anchor tag, not plaintext?  Do you understand that you need to return the html in the shortcode function?  are you saying you cannot return the html in the shortcode?  eg in the shortcode function: `$htmltext = '<a href="http://downloadlink">Download this</a>';   return ($htmltext);`

Comment: I suggest looking at the code of the free download type plugins on wordpress.org

Comment: Can you provide some examples of code from what you've tried so far?